# Browser profile which includes the proxy username and password

Tags: browser, selenium, proxy, robotframework

I am creating and running automated test scripts for certain web application. In one of the scenarios I have, I have to work with a proxy. By the way, I am using robot framework plus selenium for my test scripts. So what I did, I created a separate browser profile which selenium runs. The problem is I can't interact with the credentials pop-up (asking for my username and password) using robot framework and selenium. Is there a way where I can configure the proxy username and password to be included in the browser profile? Or is there a way where robot framework and selenium can interact with the authentication window? Any suggestions in solving or ending up with a workaround for this issue anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it proxy asdking or http basic authentification on the site?

Comment: I am not really familiar with basic authentication. But here's my setup. Browser is preconfigured on having a proxy. Upon opening of browser, I am asked for the credentials. Most probably, in my understanding, it is the proxy asking. The problem is I have no idea on how to type in the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Robot Framework SeleniumLibrary uses Selenium RC internally. Proxy authentication can be defined when Selenium server is started, see http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#proxy-configuration for details.

So, if you start the server manually, just follow the above instructions. If you are using Start Selenium Server keyword, you can give those parameters as arguments:

```
| Start Selenium Server | -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com | -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 | -Dhttp.proxyUser=username | -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password |
```

Comment: Lets say I am not using the Start Selenium Server keyword since Selenium Server automatically runs on startup. Is there a way I can enter the proxy username and password with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt get this working with my proxy, so i set up a squid proxy, which connects to the parent using the credentials and offers a local free proxy to work with.
For me this is the most easy setup / solution.

Answer (score 0):

Though its late to answer but I thought it will add value to previous answers.
There is a one more simple and quickest way, If it helps then great!

If you are running selenium server from cmd then

1. Start cmd with admin rights (run as administrator) so server is also started with admin rights,
2. Now run application, It may ask for username and password again but don't worry - just fill username and password or click cancel (in case of site running on localhost), and it will work like. (now it works as if it is passing username and password to browser or application)

   Also if don't want to fill authentication details manually every time then in your script include this code:

> System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "); 
> System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort"); 
> System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "proxyUser"); 
> System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "proxyPassword"); 
> System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "proxyExceptions");

I just had a intuition and it worked like charm:-)

Hope this quickest way saves time and efforts both for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Authorization popup can be handled in the next way:

http://user:password@securedsite.com *(In case your site is: http://securedsite.com)*